# Why do I get conflicts in my Git merge?

Tags: git, merge, merge-conflict-resolution

I get conflicts on a merge between two local branches when only one has changed.  Worse still, the conflict markers make no sense.  This has happened twice now.  Can someone tell me what is going on here, and how to avoid it?

It looks as if the merge is comparing the left and right versions of the file with the base but not with each other.  I get conflicts on stuff that hasn't changed for a while.

### Detail

The repo. has two branches, 'master' and 'dev'.  The workflow ran like this:

1. Created new repo. and copied in existing code by hand.
2. `git checkout -b dev`
3. [a bunch of commits.]
4. `git checkout master; git commit --squash dev`
5. Manually copied away code into our release procedure.
6. Time passes; made a few commits against master to fix small bugs.
7. `git checkout dev; git merge master`

At this point the problems began.

Firstly: I got merge conflicts. That makes no sense to me; the only changes were in 'master'. The three-way merge should have resolved cleanly.

I think that the use of commit --squash has made the base file for the merge a lot older than it would otherwise be, but I've compared all three versions of the file in question manually, and I still don't see it.  Most of the marked changes are sections that are missing from the base but identical in the left and right versions.  Shouldn't merge see that as no change?

Secondly: the merge markers I have are broken.  The parts that come from the left version don't match the parts that come from the right version.  Is that normal?

Some example code. The only actual change here is the addition of the line `def buffer b-product for product.` (See how the "SKU Missing" code is in the left-hand chunk of the first conflict block, but the right-hand chunk of the **second** conflict block?):

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
    if not avail b-orddet
    then
        {&throw} ("No gapnet-orddet record", 300).

    op-errorred = no.

    /** SKU missing **/
    if b-orddet.sku = ?
    or b-orddet.sku = ""
    then
    do:
        run make_report_line
            ( input b-orddet.order-num,
              input b-orddet.line-no,
              input "e",
              input "SKU not set" ).

        op-errorred = yes.
    end.
=======
    def buffer b-product for product.

    if not avail b-orddet
    then
        {&throw} ("No gapnet-orddet record", 300).
>>>>>>> master

    op-errorred = no.

<<<<<<< HEAD
    /** SKU doesn't match an Accord product **/
    if not can-find( product
               where product.p-code = b-orddet.sku )
    then
    do:
=======
    /** SKU missing **/
    if b-orddet.sku = ?
    or b-orddet.sku = ""
    then
    do:
        run make_report_line
            ( input b-orddet.order-num,
              input b-orddet.line-no,
              input "e",
              input "SKU not set" ).

        op-errorred = yes.
    end.

    find b-product
        where b-product.p-code = b-orddet.sku
        no-lock no-error.

    /** SKU doesn't match an Accord product **/
    if not avail b-product
    then
    do:
>>>>>>> master
```

Comment: It appears that `git merge -s recursive -X theirs` behaves sanely and as I would have expected. Which is fine, but how am I supposed to know when I need to do that?

Comment: If you set `merge.conflictstyle` to `diff3` you will get sequences of `<<< original ||| base === new >>>` that often make it easier to see why git's merge picked what it did.  Sometimes this is because the base version is too different from both other versions, causing false synchronization ... in which case, sometimes turning on `patience` supposedly helps; see also `--diff-algorithm=`.

Comment: **git merge -Xignore-all-space** or **git merge -Xignore-space-change** ??

Comment: @Torek: --patience and --diff-algorithm are options on `git diff`, not `git merge`?  What did you mean me to try?

Comment: `git merge` has `-X` to pass options to the chosen strategy.  `-X patience` turns on diff patience, and `-X diff-algorithm=` allows you to specify the diff algorithm (so `-X patience` equals `-X diff-algorithm=patience`, presumably).

Answer (score -1):

if you want to merge from master to branch

```
git fetch origin/branch
git reset --hard origin/branch
git pull
git merge master
```

Comment: Nope, I don't. For more information, please read the question.